# How to hide event subscription of the first member in inheritance

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance

I have the following inheritance structure in my WPF application:

[image]

In `WindowAlpha`, there is an `Activated` event subscription:

```
public class WindowAlpha : Window
{
    public WindowAlpha()
    {
        Activated += (x, y) => MessageBox.Show("Started");
    }
}
```

The WindowBravo class doesn't do anything about that event:

```
public class WindowBravo : WindowAlpha
{
}
```

In MainWindow, I intend to get rid of that subscription, so I tried this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : WindowBravo
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Activated += (x, y) => { };
    }
}
```

Also tried this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : WindowBravo
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        base.Activated += (x, y) => { };
    }
}
```

None of these usages affect *the very base of the inheritance.*

What can I do to hide that base Activated event handling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With anonymous delegates you can't. The only way that I know of is to use a actual method that is virtual.

```
public class WindowAlpha : Window
{
    public WindowAlpha()
    {
        Activated += MyOnActivated;
    }

    protected virtual void MyOnActivated(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Started")
    }
}

public class WindowBravo : WindowAlpha
{
}

public partial class MainWindow : WindowBravo
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void MyOnActivated(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
    }
}
```